# How to embedded a angular developed project url into the word press site?

Tags: html, angular, wordpress, forms, dom

I already developed a web site using angular for the inventory. Suppose that url is `https://inventory.example.net/search`

Now I want to embedded above url into the page in the main site which was developed by using WordPress. Suppose that WordPress site has 5 tabs and one is called "Inventory". `(https://www.example.net/inventory)`.

How can we display `https://inventory.example.net/search` contents when some one press on "Inventory" tab in [www.example.net](http://www.example.net) site?.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an iframe:

`<iframe src="https://inventory.example.net/search" title="information about website"></iframe>`

Check out https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.ASP for information on iframes to make sure it's right for this use case.